# How we can use ForEach in counting some data in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I like to to know if we could count or some mathematic inside ForEach, here is my code, I want get count of A and B after finishing ForEach loop. Is it possible?

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var appData: [String] = ["A", "B", "A", "A", "B"]

var body: some View {

    
    ForEach(appData, id: \.self) { item in

        Text(item)
            .font(.title)
            .bold()
            .foregroundColor(item == "A" ? Color.red : Color.blue)

    }
    
    Text("Count of A: ")
    Text("Count of B: ")
    
    
    
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not use `ForEach` for that - it is not a control flow operator, it is view container. You might not get iterated all content in `ForEach`, eg. List, Form, LazyXStack, which took only visible items from dynamic container. You should solve that working with data (eg, using `for`, `reduce`, etc.), but not with views.

Comment: I also thought if we could even do mathematic and get control of flow, it would not be best way, because we do not know how many times this ForEach loop would be get internally run for maintaining views, and in that way would be the calculation done so many repeating loop and load for cpu and memory, Am I right?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var appData: [String] = ["A", "B", "A", "A", "B"]
    
    var body: some View {
    
        
        ForEach(appData, id: \.self) { item in
          let Calculation = 1 + 2
          return  Text(item)
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(item == "A" ? Color.red : Color.blue)
    
        }
        
        Text("Count of A: ")
        Text("Count of B: ")
        
        
        
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare two computed properties outside the body:

```
var aCount: Int {
    appData
        .filter { $0 == "A" }
        .count
}

var bCount: Int {
    appData
        .filter { $0 == "B" }
        .count
}
```

and then. use them inside like this:

```
Text("Count of A: \(aCount)")
Text("Count of B: \(bCount)")
```